# Have a trigger fire "Across" a junction object

Tags: apex, trigger, delete

I have three objects in a many to many relationship. ObjectOne, ObjectTwo and they are joined by the junction Object, ObjectMiddle.

I have a field on ObjectOne that has a text field that holds a JSON string of all instances of ObjectTwo it is linked to (there is a valid reason for this I realize the list could be queried on demand but there is a legitimate reason we need it in JSON on the ObjectOne).

The JSON list is updated by a trigger on the junction object. Anytime a junction object is added, updated or delted the JSON string in Object one is rebuilt. However it should also be rebuilt whenever an instance of ObjectTwo is deleted.

So I need to, when an ObjectTwo is deleted, get a list of all ObjectOne's it was linked to, and then run an update on the ObjectTwo's using a list of their IDs'.

I have not been able to figure out a way to do this. If I use trigger.old to get the Ids I have to use the After Delete trigger, but then I can't query the Object middle to get the ID's because the relationship no longer exsists.

If I use before delete I just refresh the list, then delete and have an outdated list.

Can anyone think of a way to do this?

Comment: Can you use the ID in trigger.old to find all instances of that ID in the JSON string? Something like: select Id from objOne where JSONField.contains(trigger.oldMap.keyset())    ?

Comment: No, I can't the Id isn't in the JSON string, just the names of the elements. What occurred to me after asking this is to write a new version of the code that updates the JSON, pass the name being deleted to it, then having it skip over putting that name in the list.

Comment: It seems like what you want can be accomplished with [dlrs](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

Comment: when objectTwo is deleted, are the corresponding ObjectMiddles also deleted? and if so, by cascade delete or by trigger on ObjectTwo? The latter will give you some useful options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that getting the middle records is difficult in a simple after delete (did you try with ALL ROWS keyword?) due to clearing of relationships etc on delete

In the before delete trigger on object two, store the ID's of Object One from the related Object Middle. Then after delete, use that list to rebuild the JSON on Object One. Looks similar to this

```
public class rebuildJSON{
    public static Set<ID> objectOneIds = New Set<ID>();

    public static void rebuild(){
         //Rebuild Here
    }
}
```

Trigger:

```
trigger gatherIds on ObjectTwo(before delete, after delete){
    if(trigger.isBefore){
         for(ObjectMiddle om : [Select ObjectOne__c From ObjectMiddle Where ObjectTwo__c In :trigger.old])
             rebuildJSON.objectOneIDs.add(om.ObjectOne__c);
    }else{
         ....process IDs and rebuild JSON string on Object One Records....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was not trying the "With All" keyword (mostly because I was not aware of it), that fixed the problem.